# Spark with Cassandra: Failed to register spark.kryo.registrator

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark, kryo

Currently I encounter some problems when I try to run Spark with Cassandra on standalone mode.

Initially, I run successfully with parameter mater="local[4]" in SparkContext.

Then, I try to move to standalone mode. What I used are:

Ubuntu: 12.04
Cassandra: 1.2.11
Spark: 0.8.0
Scala: 2.9.3
JDK: Oracle 1.6.0_35
Kryo: 2.21

At first, I got "unread block" error. As suggestion in other topic I change to use Kryo serializer and add Twitter Chill. Then, I get the " Failed to register spark.kryo.registrator " in my console and the Exception as below:

```
13/10/28 12:12:36 INFO cluster.ClusterTaskSetManager: Lost TID 0 (task 0.0:0)
13/10/28 12:12:36 INFO cluster.ClusterTaskSetManager: Loss was due to java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoDeserializationStream.readObject(KryoSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcast$.read(HttpBroadcast.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcast.readObject(HttpBroadcast.scala:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:435)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask$.deserializeInfo(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.readExternal(ResultTask.scala:129)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Someone also encountered the EOFException in spark before, the answer is not register the registrator correctly. I register the Registrator following the Spark guide. Registrator as below:

```
    class MyRegistrator extends KryoRegistrator {
        override def registerClasses(kryo: Kryo) {
            kryo.register(classOf[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Map[String, ByteBuffer], Map[String, ByteBuffer])]])
            kryo.register(classOf[String], 1)
            kryo.register(classOf[Map[String, ByteBuffer]], 2)
        }
    }
```

And I also set the property just as the guide does.

```
    System.setProperty("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    System.setProperty("spark.kryo.registrator", "main.scala.MyRegistrator")
```

Can anyone give me some hints where I did wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, the reasons to get the "EOFException" and the "data unread block" are the same. They lack some libraries when running on the clusters. The most wired thing is that I have add the libraries with "sbt assembly" in spark and the libraries are actually existing in the jars folder. But the spark still cannot find and load them successfully. Then I add the libraries in the spark context, it works. That means I need to transport the libraries to each nodes by specifying in the code.

Comment: `SparkContext.addJar()` is Spark's [preferred way of shipping code to the cluster](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html#shipping-code-to-the-cluster).  I don't recommend modifying Spark's own build to add custom libraries (if you tried this and it didn't work, you probably needed to copy the updated Spark assemblies to the worker machines; this is inconvenient, which is why I'd stick to `addJar()`).